# Add less than integer variable to string search

Tags: vb.net

I'm scanning a text document for certain installed programs on a computer and looking for an easy way to include a greater or less than variable in the string I'm scanning for.  Here is a very ugly and cumbersome example of what I'm using currently and while it works as a temporary fix, isn't practical or sustainable.

```
If CheckBox2.Checked Then
            sReader.Close()
            If text.Contains("Adobe Flash Player 11 Plugin") And
                text.Contains("Adobe Flash Player 11 ActiveX") Then
            Else
                If text.Contains("Adobe Flash Player 12 Plugin") And
                text.Contains("Adobe Flash Player 12 ActiveX") Then
                Else
                    If text.Contains("Adobe Flash Player 13 Plugin") And
                text.Contains("Adobe Flash Player 13 ActiveX") Then
                    Else

'(Goes ahead and does a silent install of the missing or outdated program)
```

So far I've run into this problem with both Adobe Flash and Java RTE and am certain to run into it with future programs.  Essentially I need to scan for "Adobe Flash Player (Any number less than 11) Plugin" , "Adobe Flash Player (Any number less than 11) ActiveX" , "Java (number less than 9) Update (any number)".

I'm sure whatever solution is offered can likely be adapted to similar programs I'm likely to encounter later.  Thanks

----- Edit -----

I've since tried the following code but it always returns the "Found" messagebox, even when no version of adobe flash is present in the file it is scanning.

```
 If CheckBox2.Checked Then
            sReader.Close()
            Dim options As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.None
            Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("Adobe Flash Player (?<version>\d+) (Plugin|ActiveX)", options)
            Dim input As String = "Adobe Flash Player 11 Plugin"
            ' Get match
            Dim match As Match = regex.Match(input)
            Dim version As String = match.Groups("version").Value
            If (match.Success) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Version 11 or higher found, skipping install")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Version 11 or higher not found, installing Version 11")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can be fairly confident that the strings will always have the same format, you could use a Regular Expression to find a match and obtain the version number.

EDIT:

Here's a code snippet:

```
Dim options As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.None
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("Adobe Flash Player (?<version>\d+) (Plugin|ActiveX)", options)
Dim input As String = "Adobe Flash Player 11 Plugin"
' Get match
Dim match As Match = regex.Match(input)

Dim version As String = match.Groups("version").Value
```

The "version" variable now contains the version number

Cheers

Comment: Well, there will always be a match no matter what version number is found within the input string. I suggest you check only the value of the version variable to base your decision upon

Comment: What I meant is, as long as you code finds a string wich matches "Adobe Flash Player XX Plugin", no matter what XX is (as long as it's a number), it will return true

Comment: I see, I was looking for something that returned a true value only if the number was 11 or greater.  I could have made a mistake, but it also seems to be returning a true value even if no version of adobe flash is found.

Comment: Once you have the version number, you can pretty much do what you want with it. Convert it to an Integer, then you can do: If v > 11 Then Whatever()

Comment: If you don't mind, post your input file somewhere, and I'll figure out why it finds a match

Comment: I think I see what you were getting at now.  I was trying to blend the two solutions offered by using: My mistake, and thank you for your time

Comment: I added the new code to my original question since I can't fit it in a comment or answer my own post.  I could be mistaken but I think the error is in this line which I took from the other poster:  If (match.Success) Then

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using Regular Expressions to do you matches.

something like this perhaps:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("Adobe Flash Player \d+ (Plugin|ActiveX)")
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input_to_match_against)

if(match.Success){
  ' do something here
  Dim version as String = m.Groups(1).Value ' Will give you the version of Adobe
}
```

I apologize if the code doesn't quite work, I'm translating from C# having never used VB.

Also might be useful to build your [Regular Expression Cheat Sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet). It's meant for C#, but since you're using .NET, I expect the regex syntax should be identical.

Comment: You're not capturing the version number, so this will actually return "Plugin" or "ActiveX"

Comment: @mrlucmorin ah yes, you are correct. I use regular expressions so infrequently, and each language has its own subtle variations that I have to relearn it every time.